# Check if an lttng trace point is enabled with filter from C++ application

Tags: c++, trace, lttng

Using lttng (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lttng-ust.3.html) from a C++ application, is it possible to check if a trace point is enabled with filter option? Trace points can be enabled with filtering on the traced parameters, and i would like to read this filter from my C++ application somehow.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/lttng-enable-event.1.html, --filter option.

Say a trace point traces an integer id and a string message. I want to check if the trace point is enabled with filter option, and if so what that filter is set to.

In our system, the trace quickly fills trace buffers unless it's filtered. The reason to read the filter from the application would be that the traced data is also quite costly to produce. It would be beneficial performance-wise to only produce the data that will pass the trace filter.

Comment: I do not think LTTng exposes an easy way to do this. As of today, you do have `lttng_ust_tracepoint_enabled` to know if a tracepoint **could** end up emitting an event but it does not take into consideration payload and you do not have any way to know if the event will pass the filtering stage. You might be able to do it in a 'hackish' way via the trigger and notification subsystem with a bit of usage of the liblttng-ctl API but I doubt it would satisfy your requirement. What do you plan on doing with the resulting filter value?

Comment: Edited to answer above question